# Kendo Grid - Filtering with html content is not working

Tags: html, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, filtering

I'm trying to filter a column with HTML code in it.

I Have the following column declaration:

```
{
    "field": "status",
    "title": "Status",
    "editor": statusDropDownEditor,
    "template": "<div class='is#=status.diff#'>#=status.val#<\/div>",
    "filterable": {
        "cell": {
            "showOperators": false,
            "template": function (args){
                args.element.kendoDropDownList({
                    dataSource: [
                        { id: 0 , val: '' } ,
                        { id: 1 , val: '' }
                    ],
                    dataTextField: 'val',
                    dataValueField: 'id',
                    valuePrimitive: true
                })
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the editor function

```
function statusDropDownEditor(container, options) {
    if(options.model.status.editorDisabled){
        return;
    }
    let status = {
        autoBind: false,
        dataTextField: "val",
        dataValueField: "id",
        dataSource: [
            { val: "", id: "0" },
            { val: "", id: "1" }
        ]
    };
    $('<input name="' + options.field + '" data-text-field="val" data-value-field="id" data-bind="value:' + options.field + '" />')
        .appendTo(container)
        .kendoDropDownList( status );
}
```

The ajax value for this column is:

```
{
    diff: false
    editorDisabled: false
    id: 0
    val: ""
}
```

Despite this setup, when I try to filter by , the grid does not filter by that value.

This is the setting before the filtering effect
[image: This is the setting before the filtering effect]

And this after the filtering
[image: And this after the filtering]